# Limits in a closed interval

Tags: general-topology, limits, proof-verification, continuity

I have the following result:

$$\forall c\in S \,\,\, \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} F(c+x) = F(c) $$

Using a theorem prover, I can prove the result if I assume:

1. $F$ is continuous on $S$
2. **The interval $S$ is open**

Why do I have to assume an open interval for this result? Can I not show it if S is closed?
I'm struggling to understand the intuition behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why you need the interval to be open is because you want everything to be well defined. Your function $F$ is only define on a set $S.$ If $c$ is on the boundary of $S$, then for some $x$, $c+x \not\in S $ and so $F(c+x)$ doesn't make any sense. In that case you need to restrict the limit to elements from your set.